# "Script Task" missing in SSIS Visual Studio 2019

Tags: database, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, script-task

My Visual Studio SSIS is missing the "Script Task" tool. There is only "Script Component" tool.

[image]

I tried to search google for this problem but there wasn't anyone who had encountered the same problem as me. I tried to go to the Extension Download tab but I can't find it either.
There is no guide on the internet about how to install Script Task so I think it should be installed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSIS Toolbox is context sensitive. The given screenshot reflects the contents available for a Data Flow "Task". If you click the Control Flow at the top of the package, it will change back to the Control Flow which is where you can access the Script Task.

If you see Task, then you're in the Control Flow design environment. If you see Component, then you're in a the Data Flow *Task* design environment.

Control Flow toolbox

[image]

Data Flow toolbox

[image]

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much! I literally spend 40 minutes on google and can't find this simple thing